# Python - Converting a year beyond 3000 is not happening using to_datetime() function

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a date in the format 30191209 in a dataframe. This needs to be converted to 3019-12-06. I used the below code, but i still face issue where the converted format returns Blank.

```
df['Formated Date'] = df['mat date']
df['Formated Date'] = df['Formated Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(int(x)), format='%Y%m%d', errors = 'coerce'))
df['Formated Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Formated Date']).dt.date
```

Now, where ever the date = 30191209 is appearing, the value is blank.

Could you please help with this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do that with pandas since it exceeds the [max timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.max.html). Try using a [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) object:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Formated Date':['30191206']})
df['Formated Date'] = df['Formated Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d').date())
print(df)


  Formated Date
0    3019-12-06
```